# R 4.2.1 Start up, clean console

Tags: r, console, rstudio

I know that I can use "ctrl + L" to clean the console anytime but I really hate having to clear the version and warranty message every time I start R.

In RStudio I have changed my '.Rprofile' to

```
.First <- function() {
cat('\f')
cat('Would You Like To Play A Game?')
}
```

This works for RStudio but nothing seems to work for R 4.2.1, I have already tried...

```
cat('\014')
```

If anyone knows a solution that would include or at least work for R 4.2.1 I would be very appreciative.
Thank you in advance/

Comment: Out of idle curiosity I'm curious how cleaning the console is useful? I presume just aesthetic preference?

Comment: I don't know how to convince RStudio to change the arguments, but `R -q` will start R quietly (as communicated in `R --help`). I'm able to effect the change in my emacs/ess, so I know it works, not sure how to do it in RStudio.

Comment: i would prefer for the console to be clean for aesthetic and production purposes, I use R to collect data from across our facility and it would make it eeassier for others to input the data with a clean console on start up

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a beginner in r, but this is what I usually use to clean the console:

```
cat("\014")
rm(list=ls())
if (is.null(dev.list()) == FALSE){dev.off()}
```

I hope it helps. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: And you put this in the .First function inside the .rprofile?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I just put this in the R script when I need to clean the console.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe this will help you: https://appuals.com/how-to-clear-console-in-r-and-rstudio/